# Local Currency IDR [Indonesian Rupiah] giving Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, payment, currency

When a user's current country and preferred currency do not match, several problems arise for certain users (especially those from Indonesian country). For example:

- Consider a user from Jakarta with a preferred currency of Indonesian Rupiah. When User try and Pay Facebook gives Error "Couldn't complete purchase - Some thing went Wrong while processing your payment."
- When we ask such users to change their preferred currency, we are told - and have observed - that many countries / currencies are missing from the options listed here.

The debugger gives no error:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# 
fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# 
product: http://ogp.me/ns/product#">

<meta property="product:price:amount" content="1.00">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD">

<meta property="product:price:amount" content="1.20">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="NZD">


<meta property="product:price:amount" content="20000">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="VND">

<meta property="product:price:amount" content="10000">
<meta property="product:price:currency" content="IDR">

</head>
```

Pay Dialog Inserted like :

```
FB.ui(
 {
  method: 'pay',
  action: 'purchaseitem',
  product: url,
  quantity: quantity,   
  request_id: FbAuth.orderId
 }
```

But there is always a problem In payment Mode.. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

We got a payment on IDR. Facebook seems to have found and fixed the problem !